# Session Storage

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to figure out how to use session store for my website to pass and read information.

I need sessionStorage to pass information from my item sale page to a new purchase summary page, which will display a list of the items purchased,  the number purchased, a sub-total for each item, a subtotal for all items purchased, the tax on the purchase (7.4%), and the total amount of the purchase.   The sessionStorage variables should be stored when the unload event occurs in the body of the item sale page and the purchase summary page should read the sessionStorage variables when the onload event occurs in the body.

Comment: which technology are you using? are you using asp.net or java or else?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class like Salesdata to hold the variables and store that in session by Session["salesdata"] = SalesdataObj;
and retrieve in the other page by Salesdata obj = (Salesdata)Session["salesdata"]

Answer (score 0):

How to create and store a Cookie:
The cookie in this example will store the name of a visitor. The first time a visitor arrives to the web page, he or she will be asked to  fill in her/his name. The name is then stored in a cookie. The next time the visitor arrives at the same page, he or she will get welcome message.

First, we create a function that stores the name of the visitor in a cookie variable:

```
    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
    {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";
    expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

The parameters of the function above hold the name of the cookie, the value of the cookie, and the number of days until the cookie expires.

In the function above we first convert the number of days to a valid date, then we add the number of days until the cookie should expire. After that we store the cookie name, cookie value and the expiration date in the document.cookie object.
Get a Cookie Value

Then, we create another function that returns the value of a specified cookie:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
```

The code above uses the indexOf() method to search for a cookie name inside the document's cookie string.

The first indexOf() method will return the position where the cookie is found. The " " + and +"=" is added so that the method don't find names or values containing the name.

If the method returns -1, the cookie may still exist at the very beginning of the cookie string. To eliminate this, another search is added, this time without the " " +.
Check a Cookie Value

Last, we create the function that displays a welcome message if the cookie is set, and if the cookie is not set it will display a prompt box, asking for the name of the user, and stores the username cookie for 365 days, by calling the setCookie function:
     function checkCookie()
     {
     var username=get

```
Cookie("username");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

For more information see: [JavaScript Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

For Sessionstorage I use sessionJS, it helps to make it easier to read, write and delete sessionStorage items.

Have a look at:
https://github.com/Bart-Holland/sessionJS

Maybe this will help you as well.

Though you might want to use localstorage in stead of sessionstorage.
In u nutshell the difference is when closing the browser you keep the localstorage while the sessionstorage will be deleted.